# How to solve this sing In error while using Google Sign In PlugIn flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, flutter-dependencies, google-signin

I am trying  to authenticate users with google sign in using GoogleSingIn Package. But it's throwing this error:

```
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'signInWithAuthProvider'.
        await _delegate.signInWithAuthProvider(provider),
```

I don't understand it. I have tired flutter clean etc...but nothing worked.

Comment: The error message "Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'signInWithAuthProvider'" suggests that the GoogleSignIn package you are using is outdated or there is an issue with the package you are using.

This error is occurring because the signInWithAuthProvider method does not exist in the current version of the GoogleSignIn package. Instead, you should use the signIn method to authenticate users with Google Sign In.

Comment: I'm not sure about that outdated method or not but you can do one thing restart your ide or try (import "YOUR_PACKAGE" as libVal;) then where ever you are using this package use it like (libVal.FUNCTION_NAME)